# Modelling radioactive decay

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

The numbers in the brackets are the half-lives. Let $x_i(t)$ denote amount of substance at time $t$, $i=1,2,3...8$

This is what I have done so far. Is the set up correct?

$\frac{dx_1}{dt}=-r_1x_1$
$\frac{dx_2}{dt}=r_1x_1-r_2x_2$
$\frac{dx_3}{dt}=r_2x_2-r_3x_3$
$\frac{dx_4}{dt}=0.18(r_3x_3)-r_4x_4$
$\frac{dx_5}{dt}=0.82(r_3x_3)-r_5x_5$
$\frac{dx_6}{dt}=r_4x_4-r_6x_6$
  $\frac{dx_7}{dt}=r_5x_5-r_7x_7$
$\frac{dx_8}{dt}=r_6x_6+r_7x_7$

where $r=\frac{ln 2}{half-life}$

Comment: …32% and 82% don't add up to 100%. But otherwise it looks fine.